# addition of numbers inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it posible to add up numbers that are in a div? Basicly I want to put items in a cart and after I put items in cart I want to add up all the prices of the items to get the finnal price.
A piece of my code:

```
   <div class="div" id="contentTri29">
        <p>Naziv proizvoda: Angel eyes white</p>
        <p>Sifra proizvoda: <a href="#" class="item">001.29</a></p>
        <p>Cijena proizvoda: <div class="price">690</div></p>
        <div>
            <p><img src="~/images/farovi/angel_eyes_white.jpg" /></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div" id="contentTri30">
        <p>Naziv proizvoda: Angel eyes smoked</p>
        <p>Sifra proizvoda: <a href="#" class="item">001.30</a></p>
        <p>Cijena proizvoda: <div class="price">690</div></p>
        <div>
            <p><img src="~/images/farovi/angel_eyes_smoked.jpg" /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to conect the selected divs somehow with the div id "price"?

Comment: id's cannot be same. Also, <div="price"> is not valid. Instead, use 'price' as a class. Example: <div class="price">690</div>

Comment: saw my mistake about <div="price">, corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```js
var total = 0;

$('#add').on('click', function(){
  
  var priceList = $('.price');
  
  $.each(priceList, function(i, price){
    total+= parseFloat($(price).text());
   });
  
 $('#total').text("Total is: "+ total);
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="div" id="contentTri29">
        <p>Naziv proizvoda: Angel eyes white</p>
        <p>Sifra proizvoda: <a href="#" class="item">001.29</a></p>
        <p>Cijena proizvoda: <div class="price">690kn</div></p>
        <div>
            <p><img src="~/images/farovi/angel_eyes_white.jpg" /></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div" id="contentTri30">
        <p>Naziv proizvoda: Angel eyes smoked</p>
        <p>Sifra proizvoda: <a href="#" class="item">001.30</a></p>
        <p>Cijena proizvoda: <div class="price">690kn</div></p>
        <div>
            <p><img src="~/images/farovi/angel_eyes_smoked.jpg" /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="total"></div>
     
     <br/>
     <button id="add">Sum</button>
```

Comment: This works, but could these be done without the alert and instead write the sum of the price to another div?

Comment: yes, it is possible. Updated the answer, please verify.

Comment: Could you help me maybe with one more thing? Check this code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwmGbO    I want to add up all  the prices that I add to the cart, this code for now only adds up all the divs with the class name price, and I want to add only those prices that are added to the cart. Is this posible? I tried renaming the divs that have price  from price to cart and changing the code from price to cart but then when I try it I get 0 as price.

Answer (score 0):

Again you have multi id's the same, if you are generating the html from a database you could give your price divs an id like "product1-p" "product2-p" then give each a class of price and then iterate over the price class and add them

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
function addUp(){var sum=0;
  $('.div .price').each(function(){sum+=($(this).text()-0);});
  $('div#sum').text('sum:'+sum+'kn'); // some place to show the result ...
}
```

might do the trick. (The `-0` forces the term to be converted into a number. Implicit type conversion).